# Can't launch Finder window from terminal on Mojave

Tags: terminal, mojave, bash, iterm

`open` isn't behaving as expected on Mojave. Running

```
open /Library/
```

gives

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600 for the file /Library.
```

This happens regardless of the opening location. I'm totally lost here. Any hints?

Edit:

It is working now after letting my laptop go to sleep for a while, for whatever reason. If you run into this issue, I guess just try a reboot.

Comment: I'm no Terminal guru, but open == launch/execute. You can't launch a folder, it doesn't have execute perms, which is what the LSOpenURLsWithRole() error actually means. Someone will come along with the command you actually need, I don't know that, sorry.

Comment: `open -a Finder.app /Library`. though `open /Library` too works for me.

Comment: @Tetsujin This is not true, `open` used in the way I describe opens Finder at that location, and does work in general

Answer (score 2):

Not able to reproduce the error as I have access to Catalina's and High Sierra's macs but not Mojave. But you may want to try if **updating permissions** for your **Terminal.app** and **iTerm.app** resolved the issue:

> **System Preferences> Security&Privacy> Privacy>** add both apps to **"Accessibility"** and **"Automation"** lists
>
> **Deleting & re-adding them could also help** (it worked for me a few weeks back, re-enabling osascript assistive access to the system UI for my terminal scripts that had suddenly stopped working).

*Nota & Disclaimer: control panel headings above are Catalina's - High Sierra has only "Accessibility" - Mojave's should be close enough though -- Obviously changing any such Security settings is done at your own risks etc...* -- while I did not have to do it in my case, logoff/logon could help ensure the permissions are properly applied.

Answer (score 0):

It should be doable and you have the right general idea but what you need to do **instead** is add the " -R " flag:

```
open -R /Library
```

If you type just "open" at a command prompt you'll get the options.

Comment: This is not necessary; `open .`, for example, will open the current directory in Finder, no `R` flag needed. It is suddenly working for me now after letting my laptop go to sleep, for whatever reason.